# Websphere MQ 7.0.1 C# XMS connection causing 10054 (X'2746') tcp Error

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I have a simple program connecting to a remote queue manager which seems to work fine and I can send and receive messages. However I have noticed that with every connection I am getting errors in the windows application event manager:

> Error on receive from host myhost (12.213.143.252).
>
> An error occurred receiving data from my host(12.213.143.252) over
>   TCP/IP. This may be due to a communications failure.
>
> The return code from the TCP/IP recv() call was 10054 (X'2746').
>   Record these values and tell the systems administrator.

I thought this might be that I am not disconnecting on the client side correctly though I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is the code I am using to test connecting which is still causing this issue:

```
        XMSFactoryFactory factoryFactory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);           
        IConnectionFactory cf = factoryFactory.CreateConnectionFactory();

        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, WebSphereConfigObject.QueueManager);
        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, WebSphereConfigObject.Host);
        cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, WebSphereConfigObject.Port);
        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, WebSphereConfigObject.ServerConnectionChannel);
        cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        IConnection connection = cf.CreateConnection();
        ISession session = connection.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge);
        connection.Start();
        session.Close();
        connection.Stop();
        connection.Close();
```

any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen that event 10054 is logged by a queue manager process, amqrmppa. The event is logged when socket connection between this queue manager process and the XMS client application terminates abruptly.

Normal termination does not log any event.

Comment: so what is wrong with the above code that would cause this to terminate abruptly?

Comment: No, I don't see anything wrong in the code above. That code does not log any event for me. I am using MQ v7016. You may want to take queue manager side trace to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: ah ok, I have traced this when making a connection and have a trace file for the amqrmppa.exe process. However I have no idea where to look in this 1400 line file for things that might be happening or what to do about this where should I start?

Answer (score 0):

Try to not use the both .close calls !!!

s.   [1]: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024064

***Close and disconnect connections properly**
Code applications to properly close or dispose XMS objects that are no longer used. Failure to do so, especially IConnection or ISession instances, may limit the number connections to a queue manager.*

Comment: sorry I'm not sure what you mean which one should I not use and why?